# Java ImageIO, can't set pixel values?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have some really simple code that's just not working:

```
int[] manualPixels = new int[width * height * 3];
for (int index = 0; index < manualPixels.length; index++) {
    if (index % 3 == 2) {
        manualPixels[index] = 255;
    }
}
BufferedImage pixelImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);    
pixelImage.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, manualPixels, 0, width);

ImageIO.write(pixelImage, "jpeg", tempFile);
```

This should, as far as I can determine, output a red, green, or blue image, depending upon whether 0, 1, or 2 is used in the `if` statement in the `for` loop.  The problem is that instead of that, I invariably get blue and black stripes, no matter which pixels I set.  For instance:

[image]

I'm sure there must be some basic thing that I'm doing wrong here, I'm just not seeing what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: "I have some really simple code that's just not working": story of my life

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - JPEG is an astonishing choice for the image type.  Why not use PNG?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Because I want the output image size to be as small as possible, mostly.  The solid color images are just for testing; in practice I will be creating images which generally do not compress much under a lossless algorithm like PNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INT_RGB` packs all the channels into the least significant three octets of an `int`. This means that you are setting every third pixel to blue, and the rest are left black. (This however doesn't match with your image - did you change the code after generating it?)

Try this instead:

```
int[] manualPixels = new int[width * height];
for (int index = 0; index < manualPixels.length; index++) {
    switch (index % 3) {
        case 0: manualPixels[index] = 0xFF0000; break; // red
        case 1: manualPixels[index] = 0x00FF00; break; // green
        case 2: manualPixels[index] = 0x0000FF; break; // blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I knew it had to be some stupid oversight on my part.